# PyTorch Optimization: Is using map function on a torch.tensor without damaging computational graphs possible?

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch

I have multiple output tensors of my neural network and I want to gather them in a single list  at the end of the Forward-Propagation function. For that reason I was using `for` loop like that:

```
output = []
append = output.append
for i in range(self.number):
            append(self.out[i](input))
```

where `self.out` is a `torch.nn.ModuleList` of `nn.Sequential` layers as output of the model, `input` is input of the model and `self.number` is number of outputs.

I want to optimize this with built-in `map` method as follows:

```
append = output.append
output = map(lambda x: self.out[x](input)), range(0,self.number))
```

With both functions, outputs are same and training works. But `map` is somehow not much faster than `for` loop for self.number = 6. Sometimes even slower.

1-Might there be any wrong steps made by me, which harms the process(like damaging computational graphs) and avoids the optimization?

2-Or can't we expect perfect results from `map` for small loops ?

3-Would there be any better method to optimize a `for` loop without damaging the `torch` data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think `map` should not cause any harm. Why do you think it does?

Comment: Just because I am working with torch tensors. Dont know how far I can use built-in functions on tensors without damaging computational graphs

Comment: No, it won't damage the computation graphs

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issues speeding up my code.
I have a lot of for loops that I would like to turn into parallelized maps, but the python "map" function doesn't work in parallel.

I believe that pytorch is working on a parallel map (pmap/vmap) function like in JAX, but I don't want to wait :(

This would be very great to have, since not everything can be easily vectorized.

Comment: The PyTorch [vmap](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/prototype/vmap_recipe.html) functionality exists now.